# "Inject" callback with async/await

Tags: typescript, callback, promise, async-await

I'm refactoring some promise code to using `async`/`await`, and it works great except for one thing.

Something that a `Promise` lets you do is sort of "inject" the callback wherever you'd like. Ex:

```
public DoSomethingAsync() {
   return new Promise<void>(done => {
      // do some stuff
      done();
   });
}
```

Or even maybe the callback is wrapped up in another callback:

```
public DoSomethingAsync() {
   return new Promise<void>(done => {
      const somethingDeferred = GetSomethingDeferred();
      somethingDeferred.onsuccess = () => {
         // some success code
         done();
      };
   });
}
```

There is a similar problem with the "reject" handler.

Is there a way to refactor these to `async`/`await`? Or are they stuck wrapped up in a `new Promise...` block?

I think it's possible that the first example can be reduced all the way to simply:

```
public async DoSomethingAsync() {
   // do some stuff
}
```

Because the callback will automatically be called afterwards anyway. But the second example seems much more problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to refactor these to `async`/`await`?

No.

> Or are they stuck wrapped up in a `new Promise...` block?

Yes. You need to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) these functions that are asynchronous but don't return a promise already using the `new Promise` constructor (or a helper function that can shorten the repetitive code), there is no way around that. You'd rewrite your second example to

```
public async DoSomethingAsync() {
    await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        const somethingDeferred = GetSomethingDeferred();
        somethingDeferred.onsuccess = resolve;
        somethingDeferred.onerror = reject;
    });
    // some success code
    return …;
}
```

or, with a helper function:

```
function toPromise(somethingDeferred) {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        somethingDeferred.onsuccess = resolve;
        somethingDeferred.onerror = reject;
    });
}

public async DoSomethingAsync() {
    await toPromise(GetSomethingDeferred());
    // some success code
    return …;
}
```